# Mismatch between project architectures - how do I solve this?

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I have a solution with three projects. One uses Tesseract3, which is 32 bit, another uses EMGU 64 bit and the third is the startup project. When I run the solution I get the error message `Failed to find dll "liblept168", for processor architecture AMD64.` when . `liblept` is one of Tesseract's dependencies and is x86. The startup project has platform: Active (x86) and platform target: Any CPU. The other two have Any CPU for both.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can't run 32-bit code and 64-bit code in the same process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup project determines the "platform that is used for the application". If the startup project is "Any CPU" it will run on the default architecture of your computer (64 bit I presume). You can't use both 32 and 64 bits native libraries from within the same .NET application as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Aside from the obvious (see if you can get both libraries for the same platform) and the painful (create two applications which communicate with each other), no.